# Calculating quartiles of distributed data

Tags: statistics, distributed, distributed-computing

Not entirely sure if this is an appropriate forum for this.

I have a small database cluster(4 boxes), each machine has a shard of the overall dataset.

I need to calculate quartiles for a specific data point, but I need to do it without ever having access to the entire dataset at once.

Is this even possible?

*edit* I would prefer the exact answer, but a reasonable approximation would probably work as well.

Comment: It might be worth stating whether you require the exact answer, or would be happy with a reasonable approximation. (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compute the exact quartile in that case, but QDigest algorithm solves your problem. You can get approximations, which are reasonably good. You can check this once, Java implementation is available here :https://github.com/addthis/stream-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/clearspring/analytics/stream/quantile/QDigest.java.

With this, you can create QDigest data structure at each cluster. Its super compressed data structure, that will maintain summary of quartiles for dataset. Moreover, you can perform union of these data structures , which solves your problem.

So create an instance of QDigest at each cluster, and to combine the result, just perform union of these instances for each cluster, that will give you reasonably good approximation of quartiles.

You can follow the paper of QDigest for the detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it's probably not possible since you say the database is small. If it was a large dataset and each cluster contained a 1/4 representative sample then I guess you could compare the specific data point with the data held on one cluster.

Is there much of a discrepancy between the statistic of each shard of the dataset?

Comment: The cluster is small, but the database size is somewhat large(depending on your definition of large...maybe 100Gb total).  The quartiles would only need to calculate over say 200k points, with 50k points on each server.  The points are randomly distributed over the shards.

Comment: Well with that kind of sample size and randomly distributed shards I don't think you'd see a great variance if you calculated the quartiles over one server or all 4. Your answers wouldn't be exact, but I would expect a reasonable approximation.